# Compare Lists within parent for matching text, add class to matching text, multiples on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to compare list pairs for matching text and add a class where each matches.

There are multiple pairs on an HTML page and each pair is contained within a parent.

EG:

Group 1
 - Item 1
 - Item 2
 - Item 3

- Item 1 (match)
- Item 2 (match)
- Item Z (not match)
- Item 3 (match)

Group 2
 - Item X
 - Item Y
 - Item 3

- Item 1 (not match)
- Item Y (match)
- Item 4 (not match)

Using pure JavaScipt or or jQuery, How do I limit matches within a forEach to the current each's children?

```
$(function(){
$( document ).bind( 'ready', function() {
    $( ".groups" ).children( ".compgroup" ).each( function() {

                    $('ul.t1 li').each(function(){
        var row=$(this).html();
        $('ul.t2 li').each(function(){
            if(row==$(this).html()) $(this).addClass('match');
        });
    });
    });
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/nVtdE/89/

Comment: Hi, you have your current sample code for this?

Comment: Yes just posted thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate & put more description like match with what.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$('ul.t1 li').each` inside `$( ".groups" ).children( ".compgroup" )` each function which will loop ul elements twice.  Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $( document ).bind( 'ready', function() {
        $( ".groups > .compgroup" ).each( function() {
            var comGroupElem = $(this);
            comGroupElem.find('ul.t1 li').each(function(){
            var row=$(this).text().trim();
            comGroupElem.find('ul.t2 li').each(function(){
                if(row==$(this).text().trim()) $(this).addClass('match');
            });
        });
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mn9jk2r/6/

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! ... possible to tweak to text instead of html and add trim to allow for random spaces?